# Where to add ARIA role="main", and how to correctly mark up subsections?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, sections

I want to add the ARIA role "main" to my homepage.

I have three sections for the main content of the page:

1. Page Intro (video & page title)
2. Service summmary A
3. Service summary B

Where should I add the "main" role?

- Should I add a containing `<div role="main">` around the three sections purely for the sake of adding the role to the whole group? This seems like excess markup to me!
- Or should I add the role to the first section of the main content?
- Alternatively, should I be grouping the three sections into one `<section role="main">`, and making the three sections act as subsections?

  ```
  <body>
      <header class="site_header" role="banner">...</header>
      <section class="page_intro">
          <h1>Bold Introductory Statement Here</h1>
          <a href="#">Play Video</a>
      </section>
      <section class="service_summary">
          <h1>Section A Title</h1>
          <p>Section A content</p>
      </section>
      <section class="service_summary">
          <h1>Section B Title</h1>
          <p>Section B content</p>
      </section>
      <footer class="site_footer" role="contentinfo">...</footer>
  </body>
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to worry about excess markup. The `div` element isn't bad practice as long as you're not using it where a semantic element would be appropriate. In your case, you're trying to designate three other elements as the main content of a page. Barring any other options, it's entirely acceptable to wrap them in a `<div role="main">`.

However the good news is that there is a new semantic element called `main` which serves as a replacement for `<div role="main">`. You can wrap your three sections in a `main` element, and it will not affect your outline like `<section role="main">` would:

```
<header class="site_header" role="banner">...</header>
<main>
  <section class="page_intro">
    <h1>Bold Introductory Statement Here</h1>
    <a href="#">Play Video</a>
  </section>
  <section class="service_summary">
    <h1>Section A Title</h1>
    <p>Section A content</p>
  </section>
  <section class="service_summary">
    <h1>Section B Title</h1>
    <p>Section B content</p>
  </section>
</main>
<footer class="site_footer" role="contentinfo">...</footer>
```

(You can still add the `role="main"` attribute to a `main`, and in fact [the spec recommends this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) if you're concerned about browser support as the `main` element is still relatively new.)

Comment: Thanks, I've just done some reading on the <main> element and it's exactly what I needed.